# Insert right type of data in jquery ajax data post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this function for validation with server, posting collected fields data and getting validation response. The problem is the object I send with data is not getting through, probably because of the bad format, any idea how I can format it right? (when I copy/paste the object datas got in console.log it works fine)

This is the function

```
function validateCalculator() {
    const objectProperties = calculatorElements();
    console.log(...objectProperties);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API,
        data: {
            id: productID,
            ...objectProperties,
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The log of the spread objectProperties

```
{RolledType[material]: "1"} {RolledType[size]: ""} {RolledType[magnet]: ""} {RolledType[lamination]: ""} {RolledType[ring]: ""} {RolledType[blindFrame]: ""} {RolledType[shadowFrame]: ""} {RolledType[hanger]: ""} {RolledType[edgeProtector]: ""} {RolledType[foil]: ""} {RolledType[rollup]: ""} {RolledType[quantity]: "1"} {RolledType[variant]: "1"}
```

Comment: remove the  spread in the data object and send as array. What encoding is back end expecting? Default $.ajax is `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: data parameter doesn't work with array, is expecting a list of key-value pairs, eg. `RolledType[material]: "1" , RolledType[size]: ""`

Answer (score 0):

`objectProperties` should be a single object, not an array of objects. If you're getting an array like that, you need to convert it to an object

```
let objectProperties = calculatorElements();
objectProperties = Object.fromEntries(objectProperties.map(obj => 
    [Object.keys(obj)[0], Object.values(obj)[0]]));
```

Comment: Thanks, but `Object.properties` gives error, I used `Object.keys`, which gives back the list, but had to work on the code a bit, will update the post now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bit manyfold, but working upon @Barmar answer I reworked the function to this:

```
function validateCalculator() {
    let objectProperties = calculatorElements();
    objectProperties = Object.fromEntries(
        objectProperties.map((obj) => [Object.keys(obj)[0].toString(), Object.values(obj)[0]]),
    );

    const objectPropertiesFull = {
        id: activeProductID,
        ...objectProperties,
    };

    if (objectPropertiesFull) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: rolledTypeAPI,
            data: objectPropertiesFull,
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

So, one problem was the format of the response, had to convert it to key/value pairs, then constructed a new object with the added product ID and the properties spread in, and delayed the $.ajax, until the object is available (it was also firing too early, before the object properties existed)